# How to display first element of DataGridViewComboBoxCell inside dynamic Gridview in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to display the first element of combobox cell that is created inside dynamic `DatGridView`, as per normal combobox we can set

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

but this case is not working for DataGridViewComboBoxCell, I created the combobox cell as shown in below code, and I am adding values to that inside loop..

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell global_inhibits = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
for (int j = 0; j < Class_INHV.global_inhibts.Count; j++)
    global_inhibits.Items.Add(Class_INHV.global_inhibts[j]);
```

can any one tell me how to display first element added by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 global_inhibits.Value = global_inhibits.Items[0];
```

Comment: Glad that it work for you. Happy coding and GOD bless you in your quest to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Merely set the value. You could set it explicitly like

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell global_inhibits = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
global_inhibits.Value = "SomeValue";
```

Or use the `Item`s using indexing

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell global_inhibits = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
global_inhibits.Value = global_inhibits.Items[0];
```

I hope this helps.